# Angular: How to exclude certain param values in angular Route configuration

Tags: angular, angular-router-params

I am defining my route like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: PickUpWrapperComponent,
    resolve: { request: PickupRequestResolverService },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: fromContainers.PickUpRequestComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full',
        canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard],
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'Create', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

The type of url I connect with is `{baseurl}/3` and the routes works fine, I can read the value `3` as route params `id`.

My requirement is to exclude the path where `id=Create`, so basically this url `{baseurl}/Create` should not match with the above route pattern.

Is there any way to pass the exclude value for the `id` pattern?

Where we can define some rule which says, accept any value for `id` except for value `'Create'`

So something like,  `where id !== 'Create'`

Answer (score 0):

When going to a route, ANgular will read all routes of your configuration and go to the first one matching the URL.

This means that if you declare your "create" route before your ":id" route, then going on "create" page, will display the "CreateComponent", but going on "3" will display your "IdComponent".

[Here is a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lsjq2i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

```js
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'create', component: CreateComponent },
      { path: ':id', component: HelloComponent },
    ]),
```

Comment: No it is not working the way I want it to work. I want to add two paths `path: 'Duplicate/:id'` and `path: ':id'`, but when I go to this link `{baseurl}/Duplicate` it matches it with `path: ':id'`, while I want it to fail because it did not match with this path `path: 'Duplicate/:id'`

Comment: {baseurl}/Duplicate Would match the :id. Only {baseurl}/Duplicate/x would match the Duplicate one.

Comment: @MikeOne - Yes, I know. And that what my whole question was about that how can I make it doesn't match with a string `'Duplicate'` with `'id'`, so kind of exclude that value.

Comment: Your first comment on this answer contradicts what you stated just now. I’t unclear what exactly you need and I think this answer is probably what you need.